# Visio connnectors stuck in DB Mode

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

I created a Visio diagram using the template `Software and Database / Database Model Diagram`. I created a few database diagrams manually. Now I want to add some more tabs/pages for data flow diagrams. I inserted a new page, dropped on couple of generic shapes. I clicked the connector button and tried to create a connector between two shapes and got the message `Foreign key relationships can only be connected to entity shapes`.

These are not entities they are just shapes. How do I get connectors out of 'DB' mode so I can just connect some shapes?

Answer (score 0):

A database diagram in Visio is controlled by the database addin, the addin doesn't understand other diagram types.

You've created a database diagram and that should be that for that file. For a different type of diagram you need to create a new document.